# Can I make the Windows 8.1 on-screen touch keyboard semi-transparent?

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, windows-8.1, touchscreen

Is there a way to make the standard Windows 8.1 *on-screen* touch keyboard semi-transparent? I simply want to be able to type underneath the keyboard and still see what I'm typing, like on the picture below.

**Updated**, also posted this as a [suggestion on UserVoice](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6580762-make-the-standard-windows-8-1-on-screen-touch-keyb).

[image: windows 8 on-screen keyboard]

There is an option which (sort of) does that for the old desktop on-screen keyboard (the touchscreen keyboard which has been there since Windows XP), but this one is not really usable:

[image: desktop keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in option to customize the transparency of the default on-screen keyboard of Windows 8.1. You can either use **FeeltheWheel** or download a [3rd party on-screen keyboard.](http://freevirtualkeyboard.com/) I recommend the former option.

[Feel the Wheel (Feewhee)](http://www.nattyware.com/feewhee.php)

By using Feewhee you can easily resize windows and **control their transparency with a mouse wheel.**

You can download it as a as a **portable application (exe, 6Kb),** or in a **ZIP archive(zip, 4kb)**.

[image]
[image]

Source: [Here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/control-windows-opacity-and-size-with-the-mouse-wheel/) and [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/174622-screen-keyboard-win-7-premium-32-bit.html).

Comment: Is there some alternative way to use this Feel the Wheel program with a tablet (with no mouse)? Thanks.